# eclipse rse tcl script remote debugging

Tags: eclipse, tcl, eclipse-rse

I have dltk (tcl) and RSE installed in my eclipse.
I am able to debug local tcl scripts correctly. I am also able to edit remote tcl scripts using RSE.
Now I need to be able to debug a remote tcl script.
Is this possible and what are the steps needed to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the “DLTK (Tcl) plugin”?

Comment: @Donal yes that's exactly what I mean (I corrected the spelling). Thanks